# Sweep tokens from a one-time address without available ether

Tags: gas, erc-20, accounts

I'm generating a one-time address for each order in my store, and the order is payed with an ERC-20 token.

Is there any way I could sweep the tokens from this address, without an additional transaction to deposit some ether first (that will later cover the gas required to transfer the tokens)?

Answer (score 1):

No, right now you can't pay for transactions using ERC20 tokens.

There's the [ERC 865 proposal](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/865) to have this functionality, but it is not yet implemented.

If you are the one implementing the ERC20 token, the best you can do would be to add a custom function which can be called only by the *owner* of the smart contract, or by an *admin*, which would be able to transfer tokens from arbitrary addresses.

This owner/admin account would need to have ETH available to make the transactions though. Also, the people using the token would need to trust that the owner/admin won't transfer the tokens from their accounts.

Comment: I'm thinking that instead of having the admin/owner arbitrarily move balances, the contract could expose a custom transfer function that accepts a transfer from A to B if A's signature is included as an additional transaction parameter. This transaction will be sent from B's account, so B would pay the gas.

Comment: skimming through the discussion in that ERC 865 thread, I think they actually have a solution to that trust issue I pointed out.